# changing color scheme vim

Tags: unix, vim

I'm using VIM in red hat 5, with the black background and green letters. However, I don't like the color schema for strings ("") nor reserved C++ key variables (`int` for example it is in dark green). Could someone please give me some suggestions how could I change those default colors? 
I know, for example, to change the comment collor I do

`hl Comment ctermfg=yellow`

Comment: [Many colorschemes here.](http://code.google.com/p/vimcolorschemetest/) `:colorscheme <scheme name>` to change them...

Comment: have you tried tweaking the original `.vim` syntax-highlighting file? You can learn a thing or two by doing it since you can take a look at how existing syntax-highlighting specs are defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `:hi`, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. A list of highlighting definition will show.
The `C++` groups start with `c`.

---

`int` is a `cType`. Try:

```
:hi cType ctermfg=yellow
```

---

You can put your custom highlighting commands into `vimrc`(after `colorscheme name` and `syntax on`).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd want to customize your current colorscheme, check out this [Vivify](http://bytefluent.com/vivify/). Adjust the color editor to your specific language and then save the colorscheme file into your vimfiles.